# If statement that targets multiple buttons C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, button

How do I make an if statement that targets multiple buttons in ASP ?
For example, I want to make an if statement for 52 buttons to have green color, and when I click on them a textbox should get the text of the button and finally after clicking on the send button, one of the buttons should turn red. This is all done with a small table in SQL server management.
NOTE: The last two textboxes are just for cosmetic purposes. The textbox that needs to get the text or number of the button is the "Broj Sedista" field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try making a single event for all those buttons.

```
protected void btn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e){
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if(btn.Background == Color.green){
        textFieldName.Text = "Your text";
    }
}
```

The sender argument represents the control who started the action, so you can convert it to a button and access its properties.